# Using multiple python lists to format source data from Excel

Tags: python, excel, list

Python-3 list and python-excel question:

I have the following data source in an excel worksheet.

```
#      A     B         C         D
#1    cat   monkey    owl        koala
#2   horse  dolphin   badger     elephant
#3   zebra  rabbit    mouse      hedgehog
```

I'm using python-excel libraries http://www.python-excel.org/  to process this data using python.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname

book = open_workbook('simple.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

print ("Sheet Name is : "+ str(sheet.name))
print ("Number of Rows in Sheet: "+ str(sheet.nrows))
print ("Number of Columns in Sheet: "+ str(sheet.ncols))

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
 for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
     print (cellname(row_index,col_index),' Is ',sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value)
```

This results in the following output.

```
#Sheet Name is : worksheet
#Number of Rows in Sheet: 3
#Number of Columns in Sheet: 4 
#A1  Is  cat
#B1  Is  monkey
#C1  Is  owl
#D1  Is  koala  
#A2  Is  horse
#B2  Is  dolphin
#C2  Is  badger 
#D2  Is  elephant
#A3  Is  zebra
#B3  Is  rabbit
#C3  Is  mouse
#D3  Is  hedgehog
```

Similarly,

```
dataset = list()
datarow = list()

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
 for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
   datarow.append (sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value)
 print(datarow)
 datarow[:]=[]
```

Results in the following output.

```
#['cat', 'monkey', 'owl', 'koala  ']
#['horse', 'dolphin', 'badger ', 'elephant']
#['zebra', 'rabbit', 'mouse', 'hedgehog']
```

Instead of printing these concatenated rows I'm trying to find the best way to write them into a list that I can later use within my script. i.e I'm trying to achieve,

```
dataset = [ ['cat', 'monkey', 'owl', 'koala  '], ['horse', 'dolphin', 'badger ',    'elephant'],['zebra', 'rabbit', 'mouse', 'hedgehog'] ]
```

This is so I can then pass each "row" into a function. I hope I've explained this in a clear way. Suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean you want this?

```
dataset = []
for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
   datarow = []
   for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
       datarow.append (sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value)
   dataset.append(datarow)
```